# How to get a selected Node with Sigma JS (NEO4J)?

Tags: neo4j, sigma.js

I am trying to retrieve the selected node.

I have done:

```
    s.graph.nodes()
```

but this command returns all the graph node?

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create some lookup functions to find the node by its ID.

```js
function lookupNodesByKeyValue(sigmaInstance, key, value) {
  return sigmaInstance.graph.nodes().filter(node => node[key] === value);
}
function lookupNodeByKeyValue(sigmaInstance, key, value) {
  return lookupNodesByKeyValue(sigmaInstance, key, value).pop();
}
function lookupNodeById(sigmaInstance, value) {
  return lookupNodeByKeyValue(sigmaInstance, 'id', value);
}

var graphData = {
  "nodes": [
    { "id": "n0", "label": "A node", "x": 0, "y": 0, "size": 3 },
    { "id": "n1", "label": "Another node", "x": 3, "y": 1, "size": 2 },
    { "id": "n2", "label": "And a last one", "x": 1, "y": 3, "size": 1 },
  ],
  "edges": [
    { "id": "e0", "source": "n0", "target": "n1" },
    { "id": "e1", "source": "n1", "target": "n2" },
    { "id": "e2", "source": "n2", "target": "n0" },
  ]
};

// Initialize Sigma object
var s = new sigma({ 
  graph: graphData,
  container: 'sigma-container',
  settings: { defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148' }
});
// Set initial zoom
s.cameras[0].goTo({ x: 1, y: 1, angle: 0, ratio: 2.0 });

console.log("Node 'n2' => " + lookupNodeById(s, "n2").label);
```

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

.sigma-wrapper {
  max-width: 240px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  margin: auto;
}

#sigma-container {
  max-width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.1/sigma.min.js"></script>
<div class="sigma-wrapper">
  <div id="sigma-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so Much Mr Polywhirl for your help !!